# Move table in Javascript after clicking div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok so here's the problem. I'm trying to make tables appear once I have pressed a certain tab. 
Here is my HTML code:

```
    <div class="bar1" id="bar1">    
    <div class="tables">
      <table id="statistics" class="table table-condensed table-striped"></table>
      <table id="DataAnalysis" class="table table-condensed table-striped"></table>
      <table id="Inventory" class="table table-condensed table-striped"></table>
      <table id="Purchase" class="table table-condensed table-striped"></table>
    </div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.tables {
    position: relative;
    left: -5000px;
    top: -5000px;
}
```

And finally here is my javascript code:

```
$('#bar1').click(function() {
    $('#statistics').slideUp();

    $('#Inventory').animate({
      left: "500px"

    }, 200);


    $('#DataAnalysis').slideUp();

    $('#Purchase').slideUp();


  });
```

For some reason, my code is not working. I can't see the issue with my code.

Answer (score 1):

html:

```
<div class="bar1" id="bar1">click</div>
    <div class="tables">
      <table id="statistics" class="table table-condensed table-striped"></table>
      <table id="DataAnalysis" class="table table-condensed table-striped"></table>
      <table id="Inventory" class="table table-condensed table-striped"></table>
      <table id="Purchase" class="table table-condensed table-striped"></table>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$('#bar1').click(function() {
    $('.tables').toggle()
  });
```

css:

```
.tables {
    display:none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2j0tb0vy/

Answer (score 0):

Like Soronbe said, or if you cannot have the .tables div set to display:none, like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#bar1').click(function() {

    $('.tables').toggleClass('showtables');
    $('#statistics').slideUp();

    $('#Inventory').animate({
      left: "500px"

    }, 200);


    $('#DataAnalysis').slideUp();

    $('#Purchase').slideUp();



    })
      });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w56t39pg/2/